# C# when do I need locks?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have read something about threadsafety but I want to understand on what operations I need to put a lock.

For example lets say I want a threadsafe queue/
If the deqeue operation will return the first element if there is one, when do I need a lock? Lets say i'm using an abstract linked list for the entries.

Should write actions be locked? Or reading ones? Or both?

Hope if someone can explain this to me or give me some links.

Comment: Strange, that you have to ask here on SO, since concurrency and atomic operations and all that stuff should be covered _very well_ in a lot of books and online (blog) articles, since it is a very "old" concept.

Comment: Why not use `ConcurrentQueue<T>` or `BlockingCollection<T>`? Avoid explicit locking whenever you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronization in concurrent scenarios is a very wide topic. Essentially whenever two or more threads have some shared state between them (counter, data structure) and at least one of them mutates this shared state concurrently with a read or another mutation from a different thread, the results may be inconsistent. In such cases you will need to use some form of synchronization (of which locks are a flavor).

Now going to your question, a typical code that does a dequeue is the following (pseudocode):

```
if(queue is not empty) 
    queue.dequeue
```

which may be executed concurrently by multiple threads. Although some queue implementations internally synchronize both the `queue is not empty` operation as well as the `queue.dequeue` operation, that is not enough, since a thread executing the above code may be interrupted between the check and the actual dequeue, so some threads may find the queue empty when reaching the dequeue even though the check returned true. A lock over the entire sequence is needed:

```
lock(locker)
{
    if(queue is not empty) 
        queue.dequeue
}
```

Note that the above may be implemented as a single thread-safe operation by some data structures, but I'm just trying to make a point here.

Answer (score 1):

The best guide for locking and threading I found, is this page (this is the text I consult when working with locking and threading):

http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Yo want the paragraph "Locking and Thread Safety", but read the rest also, it is very well written.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic overview see [MSDN: Thread Synchronization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx). For a more detailed introduction I recommend reading [Amazon: Concurrent Programming on Windows](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/032143482X/).

Answer (score 0):

You need locks on objects that are subject to non atomic operations.

Add object to a list -> non atomic

Give value to a byte or an int -> atomic

Comment: You can still run into concurrency problems when assigning values to int/byte.  Check out `Interlocked` methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55dzx06b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Writing a byte or an int (or doing other atomic operation) in theory will not get you in trouble. In case of C# or .NET it is a good idea to understand how "volatile" works.

Comment: I know how Interlocked works. But I was referring to assigning a value (a=b) and not to storing the result of another operation (a=b+c) which is clearly not atomic.

Comment: My argument is that doing `x = x + 5` is not atomic, there are 2 parts to that executation, `x + 5` and `x = the result`, in between the two steps of executation, another thread sets x's value, the logic of `increment x by 5` may be overwritten.

Comment: @Dumitrescu Bogdan: Be careful because `long` assignments are not atomic on 32 bit systems.

Comment: I know .. that's why I said byte and int .. Practically I was referring to atomic operations and I gave examples. Maybe the best example should have been the classical sync example using the volatile bool. Which I guess will be atomic on any system.

Comment: Volatile bool is not atomic either... See Eric Lippert [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three.aspx) on this topic. Search for *"they do not actually guarantee that every processor stops what it is doing and updates caches to/from main memory"*

Comment: @oleksii ty, finding out that what they write in their documentation, is a true inspiration .. I will have to reconsider some ways of coding ..

Answer (score 0):

As the simplest rule of thumb, all **shared mutable data** requires locking a lock while you access it.

You need a lock when writing, because you need to ensure no people are writing the same fields at the same time.

You need to lock when reading, because another thread could be halfway writing the data, so it could be in an inconsistent state. Inconsistant data can produce incorrect output, or crashes.

Locks have their own set of problems associated with them, (Google for "dining philosophers") so I tend to avoid using explicit locks whenever possible. Higher level building blocks, like the ConcurrentQueue<> are less errorprone, but you should still read the documentation.

Another simple way to avoid locks is to make a copy of the input data for your background process. Or even better, use immutable input (data that can not change).

Answer (score 0):

The basic rules of locking

- Changing the same thing simultaneously does not fly
- Reading a thing that is being changed does not fly
- Reading the same thing simultaneously does fly
- Changing different things simultaneously might fly

Locking needs to prevent situations that do not fly. This can be done in many ways. C# gives you a lot of tools for this. Among other the Concurrent<> collection types like ConcurrentDictionary, ConcurrentQueue etc. But also ReaderWriterLockSlim and more.

You might find this free .pdf from microsoft useful. It's called 'An Introduction to Programming with C# Threads'

http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/70177/tr-2005-68.pdf

Ot this somewhat more humorous relay

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114262/6-ways-of-doing-locking-in-NET-Pessimistic-and-opt